# Cosine rule program producing incorrect results

Tags: c

I have been trying to find angles in a triangle using the cosine rule but the programme keeps giving me -1 when I run it. That is my code below I need help with this.

```
#include<studio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
// a , b and c are the lengths of the triangle.
   int a = 7;
   int b = 4;
   int c = 10;
   double Angle_a;
   double Angle_b;
   double Angle_c;
   Angle_a = acos( (pow(b,2)+pow(c,2)-pow(a,2))/2*b*c);
   Angle_b = acos( (pow(a,2)+pow(c,2)-pow(b,2))/2*a*c);
   Angle_c = acos( (pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)-pow(c,2))/2*a*b);
   Printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf", Angle_a , Angle_b , Angle_c);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `acos` is for arc cosine.  Do you mean to use `cos`?

Comment: C is case-sensitive, `Printf` needs to be `printf`

Comment: @FiddlingBits `acos` is correct. You use cosine to get the sides from the angles, you use arc cosine to get the angles from the sides.

Comment: `studio.h` should be `stdio.h`

Comment: @Barmar I didn't look at the code, just the question.  I guess the question should be changed to something like "arc cosine producing incorrect results".

Comment: Please change `2*b*c` to `(2*b*c)` etc. Aside: you don't need `pow` to compute the square of an integer, but if you change it, you'll need to cast the numerator to `(double)` before the division.

Comment: @FiddlingBits The title doesn't say that cosine returns the wrong result, it says the cosine *rule*. This is a mathematical law that relates angles and side lengths through the cosine function.

Comment: @Barmar Gotcha.

Comment: Well noted... Thanks Guys

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with associativity. When you write an expression like `x/2*a*b` it's treated as

```
x
- * a * b
2
```

Because multiplication and division have equal precedence and left associativity.

But you want

```
    x
  -----
  2*a*b
```

You need to add parentheses to force this grouping.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
// a , b and c are the lengths of the triangle.
    int a = 7;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 10;
    double Angle_a;
    double Angle_b;
    double Angle_c;
    Angle_a = acos( (pow(b,2)+pow(c,2)-pow(a,2))/(2*b*c));
    Angle_b = acos( (pow(a,2)+pow(c,2)-pow(b,2))/(2*a*c));
    Angle_c = acos( (pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)-pow(c,2))/(2*a*b));
    printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf", Angle_a , Angle_b , Angle_c);
   
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
0.578104
0.317560
2.245928
```